# Array of arrays from file in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, file-io

I would like to read an array in from a file that is in the format of

```
{{"text text text","text text","also text"},{"text text text","text text","also text"},{"text text text","text text","also text"}}
```

from a file and don't know the best way to do it. How can I efficiently split the line in order to add them to an ArrayList in a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

`string.split(",\\{")`  will return an array of entries in the line separated by commas. You could use this and some nested `for`s to fill your `ArrayList`s. Although if you're saving to Android, you should be using SharedPreferences and saving sets of items.

Example of shared prefs:

```
    // Adds an item to the shared preferences list
    public void addItemToList(String item){
        SharedPreferences itemList = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Set<String> items =  itemList.getStringSet(filter, new HashSet<String>());
        Set<String> tItems =  new HashSet<String>();
        tItems.addAll(items); 

        tItems.add(item);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = itemList.edit();
        editor.putStringSet(filter, tItems);

        editor.commit();
    }
```

Example of nested for:

```
String[] lineArray = line.split(",\\{");
for(int i =0; i < lineArray.length ; i++){
    String[] currentArray = lineArray[i].split(",");
    for(int j = 0; j < currentArray.length ; j++){
    ....
```